# Changing color before removing button

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a button that changes color of the background and then removes itself from the JFrame after a set amount of time, but instead of changing color it just stays pressed for the duration of wait.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    setBackground(Color.red);
    try{ 
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException iE) {

    }
    frame.remove(this);
}
```

Can anyone see what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sleep is occurring in the main UI thread, hence the reason the button just stays pressed.  If you want a sleep you should create a new thread, get that to sleep, then from within that thread you can get the frame to remove the button.

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            // Now do what is needed to remove the button.
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    };
}.start();
```